windows dont show up in boot (or grub)
i did this question and now the grub menu or boot menu appear, but my other operating system dont appear namely windows 11.
i search for a solution on ask but the best i found was:
i try to run the following command on the terminal : sudo update-grub
but it didnt solve the issue
(it said in the terminal: Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions )
what is the command on the terminal so it search for other os and update it to the grub or boot menu so i can use windows ?

Did you read the command sudo update-grub output? as it will tell you if it worked; the OS_PROBER won't run IF the installation media did not detect any other OSes at install time (eg. if it was on a drive that was disconnected, or disabled at BIOS to avoid problems; grub 2.06 & later default is it won't scan other drives or partitions).  There is no command to flip that setting; just edit the file & flip FALSE/TRUE flag in /etc/default/grub  OR comment out as is appropriate for your boxes install(s)

it also said : Systems on them will not be added to the GRUB boot configuration.
Check GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER documentation entry.
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...

Grub also only boots working Windows. Can you boot Windows from UEFI one time boot menu, often f12? If so then it may also be Windows settings like re enabling fast startup/hibernation, bitlocker or it may need chkdsk. If you can boot Windows check settings. If you cannot boot Windows then you need Windows repairs from your Windows repair/recovery disk or installer.

Take a look at Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?
